# Most performant matching of "any char"

Tags: regular-expressions

On https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp one finds the hint to use

> [\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*\n

instead of the standard

> .*\n

to match any character up to a newline to avoid stack overflow for huge texts (37 KB). Is the overflow the concern here, or is a matching run for the former also more performant than the latter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Emacs's regexps, `.` does not match all characters.  It is a synonym of `[^\n]`.  So the reason for using `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]` is when you want to match "any char, even a newline".

W.r.t overflowing the stack, `.*\n` should be handled very efficiently, i.e. without backtracking and without eating up the stack.  On the contrary `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*\n` is handled rather inefficiently by Emacs's regexp engine because it will eat up a bit of the stack for every character matched, so on "huge" texts it will tend to overflow the stack.

Note that the emacswiki suggests `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*` and not `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, for the stack overflow, are you sure that [\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*\n will cause an overflow? This is the contrary to what the wiki claims. Is this bcs of the \n at the end? What use would a pattern like [\0-\377[:nonascii:]]* without an ending character be then?

Comment: Any regexp which matches "anything" will eat up stack space (with Emacs's regexp engine, I mean), and I don't see why `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*` would do so less then `\\(.\\|\n\\)*`.  So I think the emacswiki is wrong on this one.

Comment: Any way (or anyone) to authoritatively clarify on this issue?

Comment: @Vroomfondel test it and see. I can imagine that the regexp with `|` might need more backtracking, but whether it actually does depends on how it's compiled.

Comment: +1. Very good to know. I've always used `\\(.\\|\n\\)*` and never even thought about `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*`. It's good to know about the latter, but it's even better to know that it doesn't add anything (so I'll stick to the one that is easier for me to read).

Comment: I find that `(re-search-forward "\\(.\\|\n\\)*")` on a large buffer gives "Stack overflow in regexp matcher", while `(re-search-forward "[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*")` does not. It seems emacswiki was right.

Comment: That is true only if the regexp ends with `[\0-\377[:nonascii:]]*` (which is rather unusual, since you might as well use `point-max` rather than search for it via such a regexp)  (for the curious: the crux of the matter is whether the set of chars that can match after the * is disjoint from the set of char that can match within the *.  If it is disjoint, then the regexp engine will skip recording intermediate steps, and hence avoid eating up stack space.  So `.*\n` and `[^a]*a` don't consume the stack, whereas `.*a` does).